# Simplex - does the matrix for tableau contains $I$ or have $I$ attached

Tags: linear-algebra, simplex, lecture-notes

I'm getting a bit mixed up with what these notes are referring to for $A$.

Here's an example :
[image]

This is expressed in tableau as follows

[image]

Which, I think, should be found from the following : 
[image]

But in the top middle cell there is $A_B^{-1}A_N$, and I'm not sure what would
be $A_N$ for the example problem.

Assuming that, for the example, the matrix is

$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1}
$$

Which is what I feel that it should be, but that table with $A_B^{-1}A_N$ is confusing me a bit

Comment: $z_1$ and $z_3$ are just slack variables used to rewrite your system into a system of the form $Ax = b$. So this is the starting point.

Comment: @Pebeto right - so the matrix $A_N$ is made up of the $z$ elements? And $A_N$ isn't part of $A$, but is an additional matrix.

Comment: You are correct

Comment: @Pebeto so for the table above that has six cells, is this table at the beginning of the process or the end?

Comment: In summary, with your notation, $$A_B = \pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1},$$ $$A_N = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}, $$ $$c_B = \pmatrix{-1 & -1},$$ and finally, $$c_N = \pmatrix{0 & 0}.$$